# How to write in frame using JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

I'm a beginner in Java, and I'm using book to learn, now I'm in the first GUI topics, and I've got a problem. I don't know why but I can't see text that I'm trying to put in the frame, this is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Ramka  {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame ramka = new JFrame();
        ramka.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ramka.setTitle("Frame");
        ramka.setVisible(true);
        Toolkit zestaw = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension rozmiar = zestaw.getScreenSize();
        int szerokosc = rozmiar.width;
        int wysokosc = rozmiar.height;
        ramka.setSize(szerokosc, wysokosc);
    }
}

class Ramkatekst extends JComponent{
    Toolkit zestaw = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension rozmiar = zestaw.getScreenSize();
    int szerokosc = rozmiar.width/2;
    int wysokosc = rozmiar.height/2;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString(" Sample text",szerokosc, wysokosc );
    }
}
```

Comment: You never use `Ramkatekst` in your example (you only declare such type but it is never used). Also `paintCompontent` should invoke its `super.paintComponent(g);` as first instruction. And you never make `ramka` visible. Either that example is purposely simplified and not meant to be run as is, or consider changing book...

Comment: What is the name of the book that you are learning java from?

Comment: Cay s. Horstmann cary cornell Java core

Comment: 1)  The two lines `JFrame ramka = new JFrame();` & `ramka.setTitle("Frame");`  can be shortened to `JFrame ramka = new JFrame("Frame");` 2) Everything **after** `ramka.setVisible(true);` can be reduced to `ramk.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`

Comment: Thank you Andrew, but can you explain to me how does setExetendedState and MAXIMIZED_BOTH works?

Comment: And also, Andrew can you tell me if i can modify the size of the text i put on the frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pshemo points out, Ramkatekst is never used. You need to create an instance of it and add it to your JFrame "ramka". So simply add this line at the end of your main method:

```
    ramka.add(new Ramkatekst());
```